# want to pass a variable from jquery with ajax to perl file and retrieve the value in the cgi page

Tags: jquery, html, ajax, perl, cgi

following is my html code :

```
following is my template code : 

<html>
<head>

<script type = "text/javascript" src = "jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
var counter = 0;
var txt1 = "group_save";
function addNew() {
// Get the main Div in which all the other divs will be added
var mainContainer = document.getElementById('mainContainer');
// Create a new div for holding text and button input elements
var newDiv = document.createElement('div');
// Create a new text input
var newText = document.createElement('input');
newText.type = "input";
newText.name = txt1+counter;
//newText.value = counter;
// Create a new button input
var newDelButton = document.createElement('input');
newDelButton.type = "button";
newDelButton.value = "Delete";
// Append new text input to the newDiv
newDiv.appendChild(newText);
// Append new button input to the newDiv
newDiv.appendChild(newDelButton);
// Append newDiv input to the mainContainer div
mainContainer.appendChild(newDiv);
counter++;
// Add a handler to button for deleting the newDiv from the mainContainer
newDelButton.onclick = function() {
mainContainer.removeChild(newDiv);
}
}
   function edit(element){
  var tr = jQuery(element).parent().parent();
    if(!tr.hasClass("editing")) {
            tr.addClass("editing");
            tr.find("DIV.td").each(function(){
                    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("action")){
                            var value = jQuery(this).text();

                            jQuery(this).text("");
                            jQuery(this).append('<input type="text" value="'+value+'" />');

                    } else {
                            jQuery(this).find("BUTTON").text("save");
                    }
            });
    } else {
            tr.removeClass("editing");
            tr.find("DIV.td").each(function(){
                    if(!jQuery(this).hasClass("action")){
                            var value1 = jQuery(this).find("INPUT").val();
                            alert(value1);
                            jQuery(this).text(value1);
                            jQuery(this).find("INPUT").remove();
                    } else {
                            jQuery(this).find("BUTTON").text("edit");
                    }
            });
    }
}
</script>

</head>
<body >
<form name="group" method="post" action="process.cgi">
<div id="mainContainer">
<div><input type="button" value="Add" onClick="addNew()"></div>
 </div>
 <div><input type = "submit" value = "Save"></div>
</form>
[% IF count > 0%]

<b>Details of Groups</b><br>

<div class= "table">
<div class = "thead">
  <div class = "tr">

<div class = "td">ID</div>
<div class = "td">GROUP NAME</div>
<div class = "td">GROUP DESCRIPTION</div>
<div class = "td">IS ACTIVE</div>
<div class = "td"></div>
 </div>
</div>

<div class= "tbody">

[%- SET i = 0;
 WHILE i < id.size; -%]

 <form  class = "tr">
<div class = "td">&nbsp; [% id.$i %]<br/></div>
<div class = "td">&nbsp; [% group_name.$i %]<br/></div>
<div class = "td">&nbsp; [% group_desc.$i %]<br/></div>
<div class = "td">[% actv.$i %]<br/></div>
<div class = "td action" ><button type="button" onclick="edit(this);">edit</button>   </div>
<form>
[%-     SET i = i + 1;
END -%]
</div>
 </body>
</html>
```

I want to edit the content of the table and that should be passed to the cgi file.
I have alert the value1 and found that, the value that i edited will be in the value1.
my requirement is , i need to pass those values to the cgi file.

I wrote an ajax call like this below the line , 
    var value1 =  jQuery(this).find("INPUT").val();

ajax call :

```
                  $.ajax({
                                    type: "GET",
                                    url : "process.cgi",
                                    data : {
                                            'value' : value1,
                                    },
                                    success : function(data) {
                                            alert("success");
                                    }

                            });
```

and in my cgi file, i tried to print the value like,

```
 print $cgi->param("value");
```

But, no values get printed there.What may be the problem?can  anyone please help me to fix this ???

Comment: and what happens if you send something static like `'value' : 123` ?

Comment: still it is not coming

Comment: i didn't use ajax before...am i using the ajax in the correct position.i am having doubt in that?could you please checjk?

Comment: Here's an unrelated tip: use Firebug and do debug output with Console.log(foo), that's a lot more convenient than having alerts all the time.

Comment: Also, check if it calls the right script at all. Try putting `warn` or `carp` in your script and look at `/var/log/apache2/messages` or similar error log for your web server. I've got the feeling there might a `cgi-bin` missing. Try this. Is your `process.cgi` executable? `chmod` it to 775.

Comment: yeah , it is executable

Comment: Could you at least remove your styles from your template code? Nobody wants to wade through tons of this stuff just to find out what is going on.

Answer (score 2):

There are many different technologies interacting here. It would be a good idea to test them one at time to see where the problem is.

1. Run your Perl program from the command line to ensure that it
   does the right thing.
2. Run your Perl program by typing a URL directly into the browser to ensure that it reacts to HTTP requests correctly.
3. Fake up a static HTML page that calls your Perl program to ensure that you're passing the correct parameters in the correct format.
4. Add jQuery and Ajax into your HTML page so that it exactly recreates
   the static form that you used in stage 3.

Don't move on to the next stage until you are sure that each stage works correctly. Only a really bad programmer would try to debug all of these technologies at the same time.

Comment: i did in the very same way.i can pass other values from this template file to my cgi page.And it is storing in the database.for the updtaing purpose i added the ajax and jquery.and this is the only thing, that is not passing

Comment: i have checked using the firebug and found that the values are passing to the process.cgi file but, it is not getting printing there.I think the format, i used to print is not right. could you please help?? and is there any use CGI:Ajax; directives required in the cgi page to get the value from the ajax call

Comment: Your Perl program knows nothing at all about Ajax. It is just an HTTP server responding to HTTP requests. As long as you send it a correctly formatted HTTP request, it should work. Why not change your Perl program to dump all of the parameters it receives. That way you can see what is going on.